# NativeWindow equivalent

Tags: c#, c++, wndproc

In `c#`, I can "hijack" the `WndProc` of a window **within the same process as the executing code**, using the [`NativeWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, giving me the capability to override certain messages and let others pass.

Here is an example:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_ENABLE:
            //do default thing
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            //then do my thing
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            //don't even call base.WndProc, I'll handle painting.
            break;
        default:
            //all other messages...
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in a `c++ Win32` application? I'm not even sure where to start or what the correct term is.

Comment: I don't know how much use this would be, but you could try looking at the `NativeWindow` class in a .NET reflector to see what it's calling.

Comment: It is called "subclassing".  That got started *long* before NativeWindow ever got around, Petzold swears.  MSDN article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The equivalent of `base.WndProc` is `DefWindowProc` in a window class you control, and `CallWindowProc` in a window you subclassed.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/07/9592397.aspx  But there's a newer, "safer" subclassing API now: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx and then you use `DefSubclassProc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [WindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback in C++ for any `HWND`.

For full details and options (there are quite a few ways to do this in the WIndows API), see [Using Windows Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The closest to your C# option would be to [Subclass a Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window).  Note that the new, improved mechanism to subclass a Window is to use [SetWindowSubclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I understand if would involve `WindowProc`, but the part I'm unclear on is how to associate it with an existing HWND.

Comment: @Rotem Added details for you.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Not knowing the correct term to search for is frustrating.

Comment: That's the old, fragile way of subclassing.  Perhaps a link to [`SetWindowSubclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be better.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point - not sure why MSDN hasn't updated in that page, but added a link.

Comment: Looks like Hans found the newer MSDN document that describes both methods, in his comment to the question.